# a href inside a span wrapping issue

Tags: css, href, html

I have the following code

```
<li>
    <span class="image">
        <a href ='xyz'> this is a long link text </a>
    </span>
</li>
```

Following CSS

```
.image {
    &:before {
    content:(../image/xyz.png); 
}
```

With the above code the text inside the a href is long and is getting wrapped below the image.I want it to wrap around from where it starts.

For example

```
   IMAGE this is a 
         long link text
```

Currently its rendering

```
   IMAGE this is a 
   long link text
```

I don't want to change the structure of the html. I could include two different spans or divs. But can this be done without it from the above code.

Comment: Is this LESS framework?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```css
.image::before {
    content: url(../image/xyz.png);
    float: left;
}
```

All you have to do is add the `float: left` property to the pseudo-element.
**Notice** that the code above is pure CSS. I also changed the `content` property a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add the following CSS:

```
.image{
  background: url(image.png) top left no-repeat;
  padding-left: 100px /* image width */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Float image left with a specific width. Text should float to the left of the image. Or to make sure add a float to the anchor tag. If this code fails, add a margin beneath the image big enough to prevent the text wrap.

```
.image img {
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
}

.image a {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```